# ’unresolved import’ message for streamlit in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: eclipse, import, pydev

I have successfully installed the streamlit package using the following
shell command and can run the resulting local server localhost:8501

```
Python3.8 -m pip install streamlit
```

In Eclipse, the module appears under the Package Library in the Python Interpreter.
I can import it as a library item in a PyDev module as as follows:

```
import streamlit
```

The only note I get from the compiler is that streamlit is an ‘unused import’. However, when I append the command as follows the compiler then says ‘unresloved import st’

```
import streamlit as st
```

Both ‘import streamlit’. and ‘import streamlit as st’ will not code complete.

How can I clear the ’unresolved import’ message ?

The sys.path is as follows:

```
/Users/davidklemitz/eclipse-workspace/streamlit
/Users/davidklemitz/eclipse-workspace/streamlit
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Turns out it was a compound of two issues.

First the name of the PyDev module I chose was the same name as the package module name streamlit.py, installed using the following command

```
Python3.8 -m pip install streamlit
```

Second, I had a look at the PYTHONPATH under Eclipse->Preferences-> PyDev->Interpreters-> Python Interpreter where these paths were arranged as follows:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages

As streamit.py was in the second and not the first, I reversed the order, restarted Eclipse, created a new PyDev project and associated development model named stream_lit.py and the code completed as expected.